# Can't see cursor in Xcode LLDB debugger

Tags: xcode, lldb

In Xcode's "All Output" aka console, when I type things like `po someObject` I can never see my cursor so I have no idea where I am when I want to go back and add some square brackets for instance:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same issue, the reason was: Xcode Theme - Background and Cursor were set to the same color.